# Can i copy the Question from stack overflow and answer it in my blog?

Tags: discussion, blog, copyright, terms-of-service

Can i copy the Question from stack overflow and answer it in my blog and place the blog link in stack overflow?

By doing this, Am I violating any of the terms & conditions?

Please let me know? Thanks

Comment: "place the blog link in stack overflow" note that just a link to your blog wouldn't constitute an appropriate answer.  You could post it as a comment, or as a link for further reading on an answer that actually answers the question within its body.

Comment: So, be clear, i shouldnt copy the questions from stack overflow, right?

Comment: I take it you didn't read the other question at all.  Go read it.

Comment: Thank you so much....I was searching for this info.

Comment: I think [this is probably a better dupe](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/15432/148672)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To expand upon what Servy said, because I've seen a number of people do this: please do not use Stack Overflow as a traffic generator for your personal blog. Taking a question from Stack Overflow, answering it on your blog, and then only posting the link onto Stack Overflow can be seen as self-promotion. This is particularly true if your blog is ad-supported, because you're effectively using the traffic of this site to make yourself money.

If we see someone doing nothing but posting links to their blog, we tend to remove those answers and provide a warning. If they continue doing this, we will probably suspend their account.

Beyond the promotional aspect of these answers, we expect answers to stand on their own and not rely on someone clicking through to another site. If you're going to write an answer on your blog, please make sure to write the core of your answer here as well, and only include a link for supplemental detail if people are curious.

Comment: Thanks for making it clear.

Comment: [Here's an example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6750591/119477) that would typify writing the core of the answer and then including a link to a blog. Of course it helps if you've already cemented your reputation in the developer community outside of SO to begin with.

Comment: hello dear Brad hello Vji - many thanks for this great thread. Well i just wonder how we can understand the sharing option on the postings - see the postings. There are various sharing options there..  like sharing it on facebook , dev.to or other sites. 

how to understand this - why is it possible - why are people allowed to do this kind of sharing . - is it consistent with the https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/

look forward to hear from you